# Comparator Design

Tags: comparator

I have designed an inverting comparator circuit with external hysteresis.

These are my calculations:
[image: Reference Design]

[image: Calculations]

[image: Schematic]

Finally the output waveform:

[image: Waveforms] The threshold of comparison is high and it's missing most of the pulses. Could you suggest what is the mistake here?
Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty simple. You need to generate separate Vrefs for the two inputs. Using the same Vref defeats the hysteresis by injecting the feedback into both the + and - inputs at the same time.

Comment: The plot isn't very useful without knowing what the Out2 input looks like. At a minimum, I'd show the waveform on both sides of the capacitor. Also, we have no idea where V(n004) is on the schematic.

Comment: @DanLaks out2 is same as V(n004), except at a slightly  lower DC voltage. V(n004) is the negative input of the comparator.

Comment: @Ash: your positiv feedback resistor (R15) for creating hysteresis is useless if there isn't also a resistor at the connection to V_ref. Also: the input signal will affect V_ref (not good; it wouldn't be a problem if V_ref wsn't also used as threshold voltage; see WhatRoughBeast's comment).

Comment: Where is your supply comming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. The easy way to solve this is to make R3>> Rpullup
2. Then Define Vo average = (Voh+Vol)/2 for 50% duty cycle
3. Then define V+in to BE THE SAME as Vo avg, without R3

   - using V+in(avg)= R1/(R1+R2)Vcc where R1//R2=Req
4. Then define %Hysteresis = (Vih-Vil)/(Voh-Vol) *100% becomes the gain for a inverting op amp = -Av = Rf/Req  except you have positive feedback so your hysteresis gain is Req/Rf.

**Unfortunately adding a CAP C6, makes your design even worse... a RELAXATION OSCILLATOR so DELETE C6 and bias Vin+ like I said above to get rid of input output average offset.** Then it will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fce8in.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Ash Does this make more sense , choosing R/1/R2 ratio to match Vo average and use formula for gain to determine hysteresis or positive feedback = 1/gain as % Hysteresis?  if you define your Vref or Veq , then you must insert Req to get a feedback ratio. You cannot use 0.8V with zero impedance(f). because then you end up with a RELAXATION OSCILLATOR, just like a Schmitt trigger inverter with R feedback and cap to ground on input.  Capiche?  Thats why you get noise pulses.  Offset voltage and differentiated oscillator.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I really appreciate it. I have few questions: a) I don't have pull up as my comparator is Push Pull not Open Drain. It shouldn't affect, should affect it?  b) I set VIH=1.2 V and VIL=1  V and VOH=4.8 and VOL=0.176, based on the calculation I get R2 as 101K and R1 as 100K and R3 is 1.16 M ohm. However on simulation, the threshold has changed to a high voltage and I don't see hysterisis. I have posted the new schematic and waveforms. Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Tweak my simulation http://tinyurl.com/mesfglb  for input thresholds and Vdd  ... this was for another recent question I answered

Answer (score 1):

Change R13 to a 27K resistor so your reference signal and your input signal are biased near each other so they will cross when an input pulse occurs. Your reference will be sitting at around 1.05 volts and your input signal will be swinging from 0.8v to over 1.2 volts. And you'll have about 0.1v swing of hysteresis.

Answer (score 0):

You need a resistor between Vref_0v8 and the comparator + so your hysterisis feedback through R15 can quickly swing the + input out of the noise region of the input signal. As it is now you have a 0.1 C16 capacitor tied directly to your + input which will guarantee that the + input changes very slowly, keeping it inside the signal noise range for a longer time.